# How do I make python modules available to all users?

Tags: linux, python, pip

I work in a multi-user setting and am relatively new to Python. The machines in question run Ubuntu 16.04, and we are using Python 2.7. I personally have installed several additional modules, such as tensorflow, keras, and some other related modules and I believe I used the pip installer (pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/) to install these (`sudo pip install X`).

I've been successfully running python scripts for months using all of these modules but another user has been unable to run any python code that uses any of the modules that I've installed. Even a 1-line script that exists only to import a module such as:

```
import tensorflow
```

fails to run, generating an ImportError (I'll only paste the last couple of lines):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 24, in <module>
import enum  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
ImportError: No module named enum
```

What did I do wrong that's making these modules invisible to other users, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend avoid using `python-pip` on production context. 
Modules installed that way aren't updated during system updates which may lead to vulnerabilities that never get patched ....

Nevertheless, pip, by default, install the module only in calling user's $HOME.
For pip to install "system-wide", use the `--system` switch.

For more details, see `pip install --help` output

**EDIT**
`--system` looks to be a debian specific option.

```
binarym@avalon:/tmp/python-pip-18.1/debian/patches$ grep -- '--system' *
set_user_default.patch:+:ref:`--system <install_--system>` option to ``pip install``.
set_user_default.patch:+            '--system',
```

Thanks @co2f2e for your comment.

Comment: where did you get that option `--system` ?

Comment: As mentionned in my answer, `pip install --help`

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file please go through the  documentation . No such option is available

Comment: You're right... Looks like my Debian implements a `pip` option that doesn't exist in uptstream. Maybe a Debian patch ?

Comment: There never been such an option @binarym

Comment: @co2f2e see my edit. I fetched the source package for `python-pip` on Debian. The `--system` is implemented by a patch that has probably been added by Debian maintainer.

Comment: this is more of a hacky way to do it

Comment: Seeing the number of response in this question ... looks like it is the "only" way to do it ? ;-(

Comment: Negative, if you install any module like pip install dependency, without specifying a user it will available for all users

Comment: no such option: --system

Comment: Did you read comments ?

Comment: "avoid using python-pip on production context" – ok. But what to use then to install dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm `pip3 --help` does not show the `--system` switch. But it was accepted. Also, I had to use this as root. Simply doing `sudo pip3 install x --system` failed.

Example.

```
sudo su
pip3 install x --system
```

Comment: no such option: --system

Answer (score 0):

## On Debian & Ubuntu 20.04

This works fine with the version of `pip` provided by Debian's or Ubuntu's `apt` repository.

```bash
$ pip --version
    pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip install --help
    Install Options:
    --system    Install using the system scheme (overrides --user on Debian systems)

$ pip uninstall modulename
$ sudo pip install --system modulename
```

However, this will not work when `pip` was upgraded with `pip` from the PyPI repository:

```bash
$ pip --version
    pip 22.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

**NOTE:** This option is unfortunately no longer available with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Ok so that that just means `--system` is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers answer the questions across platforms.
Here is a solution that works for me:

1. loremipsum not installed

```
$ sudo pip freeze | grep loremipsum
$ python -c "import loremipsum"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loremipsum'
```

2. I checked my current paths of python

```
$ python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

/usr/lib/python38.zip
/usr/lib/python3.8
/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

3. I decided to use /usr/lib/python3.8 to install packages into, as its a global path that user has access to. To do this I used the `--target` parameter in pip.

```
$ sudo pip install --target=/usr/lib/python3.8 loremipsum
Collecting loremipsum
  Using cached loremipsum-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: loremipsum
Successfully installed loremipsum-1.0.5
```

4. Confirm installed:

```
$ pip freeze | grep loremipsum
loremipsum==1.0.5
$ python -c "import loremipsum"
$
```

5. To remove the package you will need to do a `rm -rf` of the location unfortunately. This is a know issue [found here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5595). Therefore this is a workaround for now. Pay close attention to the `*` at the end of `loremipsum*` there are multiple packages that need to be removed.

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.8/loremipsum*
$ pip freeze | grep loremipsum
$ python -c "import loremipsum"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loremipsum'
```